# NTVS Moved .d.ts files now VSTSC error not found with old file location

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

So I moved my `.d.ts` files from `Scripts/typings/node/node.d.ts` to `typings/node/node.d.ts` and now it gives me the error:

```
Error 2 Build: File
'~/Source/Repos/mobiledlr/mobiledlr/Scripts/typings/node/node.d.ts'
not found. VSTSC 0 1 mobiledlr
```

Is there a way to refresh or rebuild VSTSC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that you don't have to keep your `.njsproj` file updated and work *outside* visual studio reliably you can edit it *once* to include something like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="lib\**\*.ts" />
    <Compile Include="lib\**\*.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note: you just need to be careful to add files *outside* of visual studio since it likes to overwrite this lovely glob with its expansion.

Answer (score 0):

The `.njsproj` project file had the old path references in it. I just changed them to be the correct path.

It's been a while since I've worked with Visual Studio! I forgot it did that if you edited them outside of Visual Studio!